# ResourceProvider with Sling 8.. 403 response

Tags: sling

I need to provide a Restful API in Sling, but for some data that isn't in the repo... This API will proxy to other external datastores.

Sling developers recommend creating a ResourceProvider. I've created this ResourceProvider implementation, however I'm getting a 403 when I request it:

```
@Component
@Service(value=ResourceProvider.class)
@Properties({
        @Property(name = ResourceProvider.ROOTS, value = "things"),
        @Property(name = ResourceProvider.OWNS_ROOTS, value = "true")
})
public class ImageResourceProvider implements ResourceProvider {

@Override
public Resource getResource(ResourceResolver resourceResolver, String path) {
    Resource returnResource = new SyntheticResource(resourceResolver, path, "edlio/microservice/image");
    returnResource.getValueMap().put("myProp" , "myValue");
    return returnResource;
}

@Override
public Resource getResource(ResourceResolver resourceResolver, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, String path) {
    return getResource(resourceResolver , path);
}

@Override
public Iterator<Resource> listChildren(Resource resource) {
    return null;
}
```

When I go to /things, I get a 403. How can I control the authentication/authorization rules for this resource that doesn't exist?

Also, I can't use the ResourceProvider example code [here](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/launchpad/test-services/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/launchpad/testservices/resourceprovider/PlanetsResourceProvider.java) because it uses the spi package which isn't inside of Sling 8... Sling 8 uses an older version of the sling api package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself and posted my answer here:
[Adobe CQ5 custom servlet path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194586/adobe-cq5-custom-servlet-path/41990177#41990177)

Search for the answer from lance.dolan